# There are infinitely many primes that divide $2^{n^3+1}-3^{n^2+1}+5^{n+1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$$q(n)=2^{n^3+1}-3^{n^2+1}+5^{n+1}$$

Claim: If $p>2$ divides $q(n)$ then $p$ not divides $q(n+k)$, for $k>0$
If $p|q(n)$, then $$p|q(n)(5^k)(5^{k^2+2nk+k^2})(2^{k^3+3n^2k+3nk^2})=2^{(n+k)^3+1}(a)-3^{(n+k)^2+1}(b)+5^{n+k}(c)$$
But we supposed that it's true for $a=b=c=1$, instead $a,b,c>1$
Since a prime that divides $q(n)$ does not divide any $q(n + k)$, we conclude that for every $q(n)$ there is always a different prime. So there are infinitely many primes that divide $q(n)$
Do you know if the proof is correct? I am not very sure

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing. Since $q(n)$ is a finite number, it cannot have an infinite number of prime factors.

Comment: Obviously, I rewrite better. I meant that for every prime there is an $n$ such that $p|q(n)$

Comment: I assume you mean "infinitely many primes divide at least one member of the sequence $\{q(n)\}$", yes?

Comment: Hang on, do you mean "every prime" or "infinitely many primes"?

Comment: Infinitely many primes

Comment: Right.  For example, $3$ never divides  $q(n)$.

Comment: Your claim is false, though. $7$ divides $q(n)$ whenever $n$ is an odd multiple of $3$.

Comment: barring numerical error, the first few primes $>5$ that divide some of the $q(n)$ are $7,11,41,53,59$.  No obvious pattern there...

Comment: I'm afraid your logic is rather wrong. That a prime $p$ will divide some linear combination of the three powers is totally unrelated to whether it may divide the linear combination of interest.

Comment: @math You have received an excellent answer. One month later, you should validate it. It is in this way that this site is profitable to other users.

Answer (score 3):

The equation is, for integers $n$,

$$q(n)=2^{n^3+1}-3^{n^2+1}+5^{n+1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As stated in [aschepler's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2236/aschepler) comment, your claim that any prime $p \gt 2$ which divides \eqref{eq1A} does so for only one value of $n$ is incorrect.

Instead, let $S$ be the set of odd primes $p$ which divide $q(n)$ for at least one integer $n$. Note that $S$ is non-empty, e.g., $q(1) = 4(5)$ so $5 \in S$, and $q(2) = 2(197)$ so $197 \in S$. However, as [lulu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4514682/there-are-infinitely-many-primes-that-divides-2n31-3n215n1#comment9480642_4514682) indicates, $3 \not\in S$ since odd $n$ results in $q(n) \equiv 1 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, and even $n$ gives $q(n) \equiv 2 + 5 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Assume $S$ is finite, i.e., it has some $m \gt 1$ elements of $p_i$ for $1 \le i \le m$. Let

$$n_1 = \prod_{i=1}^{m}(p_i - 1) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means that

$$n_1^3 + 1 \equiv n_1^2 + 1 \equiv n_1 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{p_i - 1} \; \forall \; 1 \le i \le m \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), and that $5^{n_1+1} \equiv 5 \pmod{5}$, we have

$$q(n_1) \equiv 2 - 3 + 5 \equiv 4 \pmod{p_i}  \; \forall \; 1 \le i \le m \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Next, since $n_1$ is even,

$$q(n_1) \equiv -3 + 5 \equiv 2 \pmod{8} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

i.e., $q(n_1)$ has exactly one factor of $2$. However, since $q(n_1) \gt 2$, it must then have at least one odd prime factor, but \eqref{eq4A} shows this is not in $S$, contradicting that $S$ contains all such odd prime factors. This contradiction means the assumption of $S$ being finite is false, i.e., there are infinitely many primes which divide $q(n)$ in \eqref{eq1A} for at least one value of $n$.

Comment: (+1)! I would love for you to write a great answer.  You are doing a great job of being a teacher.  I hope you want to write an answer...
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4528746/1089358

Comment: Thank you very much! I will read your answer later. Please ignore downvotes. Your answers are always great

Comment: @nonstudent Thank you, again, for the compliment. Please let me know if there's anything in my [answer](/a/4538502) to your other question that is unclear, you would like to know more about, etc. Regarding the downvotes, I was a bit surprised to get $2$ of them. However, since most other answers there have at least $2$ downvotes (and your question has $3$), I realize that they're likely not related to any specific answer (or your question), with something else going on instead, so I'm not taking it personally.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you can do much better, providing a lower bound for the number of prime factors $f(n)$ dividing $2^{n^3+1}-3^{n^2+1}+5^{n+1}$ for infinitely many $n$.

Indeed, by Theorem 1 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwiD7ArFWBHk69MEQQ1E_NqeJ1aXq_RF/view), there exist infinitely many $n\in \mathbf{N}$ and a real $\theta>1$ such that
$$
f(n) \ge \mathrm{slog}_\theta(n),
$$
where $\mathrm{slog}_\theta$ is the "superlogarithm" in base $\theta$, i.e., the largest integer $k$ such that $\theta^{\theta^{\theta^{\dots}}}\le n$, where $\theta$ is repeated $k$ times.

Answer (score 0):

For $p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $M(p,n)$ be the largest integer so that $p^{M(p,n)}$ divides $n$.

Suppose that only finitely many primes divide $q$ namely $z_{1},....,z_{m}$. Set $Z= \{z_{1},...,z_{m}\}$. Note that some subset $H \subseteq Z$ is ``maximal'' in the sense that $\exists n_{H} \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\left(\prod_{w \in H} w\right) | q(n_{H})$ and we have

$$H \subsetneq \mathbb{} G \subseteq Z \text{ }\Rightarrow  \forall z \in \mathbb{Z}\text{ } \prod_{w \in G}w \not \div q(z) $$

Thus for all $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q(n_{H} + \beta \phi(n_{H}))$ is a product of primes in $H$. Moreover for $\beta$ sufficiently large we have $M(h, q(n_{H} + \beta \phi(n_{H})) = M(h, q(n_{H}))$ whenever $h \in H$ (here we take into consideration if $h$ were to be $2,3$ and $5$ and apply Euler's theorem). Thus we have $q(n_{H} + \beta\phi(n_{H})) \leq q(n_{H})$ for all $\beta$ sufficiently large which is impossible.