# Find the all possible values of $a$, such that $4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4>0$ holds $\forall x\in (0,2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, solution-verification, quadratics

> Problem: Find the all possible values of $a$, such that
> $$4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4>0$$
> holds $\forall x\in (0,2)$.

---

My work:

First, I rewrote the given inequality as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}f(x)&=\left(2x-\frac a2\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0\end{aligned}
$$

Then, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
0<x<2\\
\implies -\frac a2<2x-\frac a2<4-\frac a2\end{aligned}
$$

Case $-1:\,\,\,a≥0 \wedge 4-\frac a2≤0$.

This leads,

$$
\begin{aligned}\frac {a^2}{4}>\left(2x-\frac a2\right)^2>\left(4-\frac a2\right)^2\\
\implies \frac {a^2}{4}+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>f(x)>\left(4-\frac a2\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4\end{aligned}
$$

For $f(x)>0$, it is enough to take $\left(4-\frac a2\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0$ with the restriction $a≥0\wedge 4-\frac a2≤0$.

Case $-2:\,\,\,a≤0 \wedge 4-\frac a2≥0$.

We have:

$$
\begin{aligned}\frac {a^2}{4}<\left(2x-\frac a2\right)^2<\left(4-\frac a2\right)^2\\
\implies \frac {a^2}{4}+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4<f(x)<\left(4-\frac a2\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly, for $f(x)>0$, it is enough to take $\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0$ with the restriction $a≤0\wedge 4-\frac a2≥0$.

Case $-3:\,\,\,a≥0 \wedge 4-\frac a2≥0$.

This case implies, $\left(2x-\frac a2\right)^2≥0$.  This means, $f(x)≥\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4$

Thus, for $f(x)>0$, it is enough to take $\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0$ with the restriction $a≥0\wedge 4-\frac a2≥0$.

Finally, we have to combine all the solution sets we get.

---

I haven't done the calculation, because I want to make sure that the method I use is correct. Do you see any flaws in the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is mostly correct, apart from a few fairly minor issues regarding an open set being used, and there's some work you didn't need to do. First, as you pointed out, the inequality can be rewritten as

$$f(x) = \left(2x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3a^2}{4} - 5a + 4 \gt 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

For any fixed value of $a$, then $\frac{3a^2}{4} - 5a + 4 = c$ is a constant. Also, with $g(x) = 2x-\frac{a}{2}$, then \eqref{eq1A} can be rewritten as

$$f(x) = g^2(x) + c \gt 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

To have \eqref{eq2A} being true $\forall \, x \in (0,2)$, with

$$m = \min_{x\in[0,2]}g^2(x) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

requires that $m + c \ge 0$ where $g(0) = 0 \lor g(2) = 0 \lor m \neq 0$ (i.e., points $1$ and $2$ below), and $m + c \gt 0$ otherwise (i.e., where $g(x) = 0$ for an $x \in (0,2)$, as described in point $3$ below). The first case is because the minimum value $m$ is not actually reached on the open set $(0,2)$, i.e., $g^2(x) \gt m \; \forall \; x \in (0,2)$, so $g^2(x) + c \gt 0$ means that $m + c \ge 0$.

To determine this minimum value $m$ in \eqref{eq3A} involves $3$ basic cases:

1. $g(x) \lt 0 \; \forall \; x \in (0,2)$, which is your case $1$, with $m$ coming from the upper limit value of $g(x)$, i.e., $m = (4 - \frac{a}{2})^2$.
2. $g(x) \gt 0 \; \forall \; x \in (0,2)$, which is your case $2$, with $m$ coming from the lower limit value of $g(x)$, i.e., $m = (-\frac{a}{2})^2$.
3. $g(x)$ having both negative and positive values (so $0$ as well), which is basically your case $3$ (except you should've used $\gt$ instead of $\ge$ to avoid overlapping with your previous cases, as well to ensure that $g(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0,2)$), with $m = 0$.

Regarding your analysis of these cases, note that $g(x)$ is a strictly increasing function, with its upper limit value of $4 - \frac{a}{2}$ being $4$ more than its lower limit value of $-\frac{a}{2}$ (and, correspondingly, the lower limit is $4$ less than the upper limit). Thus, for example, with your case $1$, having $4 - \frac{a}{2} \le 0 \; \to \; 4 \le \frac{a}{2} \; \to \; a \ge 8$, i.e., a stronger condition than your $a \ge 0$, so this didn't need to be mentioned. Further, as I explained in my point $1$, you only needed to deal with handling $4 - \frac{a}{2}$.

Similarly, with your case $2$, having $a \le 0 \; \to \; -\frac{a}{2} \ge 0$ means that $4-\frac{a}{2} \ge 4$, which is a stronger condition than your $4-\frac{a}{2} \ge 0$.

Finally, as you wrote, the solution is obtained by combining (more precisely, taking the union of) the sets of values of $a$ resulting from each of your $3$ cases.

Comment: This is not an accurate answer. Please check other solutions.

Comment: @FarshidFarhat What, specifically, do you believe is inaccurate about my answer?

Comment: You don't consider $g(x)$ helps when $c<0$. Check $a=6$ and $a=0.9$ which are not in your solution. The accurate answer is $a>\frac{2}{3}(5+\sqrt{13}) \approx5.7370$ or $a<\frac{8}{5+\sqrt{13}} \approx0.9296$ as mentioned by @andreas and me as well.

Comment: @FarshidFarhat You wrote "You don't consider $g(x)$ helps when $c\lt 0$". I don't understand what you mean. My solution, which is a critique of the OP's attempt as was specifically requested in the bounty message, does *not* consider valid values of $a$ with $g(x)$ and $c \lt 0$ separately. Instead, it deals with how their *sum*, i.e., $m + c$, compares to $0$ based on the $3$ possibilities for the range of values of $g(x)$. Thus, *all* possible values of $a$ are accounted for including your examples of $a = 6$ and $a = 0.9$. With $a = 6$, since $g(x) = 2x - \frac{a}{2}$, we have for ...

Comment: @FarshidFarhat (cont.) $x \in (0,2)$ that $-3 \lt g(x) \lt 1$. This is covered in case $3$, i.e., with $m = 0$ (with this occurring when $x = \frac{3}{2}$). We also have $c = \frac{3a^2}{4} - 5a + 4 = \frac{3(6^2)}{4} - 5(6) + 4 = 3(9) - 30 + 4 = 1$ (note here $c \gt 0$, but your comment indicated $c \lt 0$ is part of the problem with my answer). Thus, this shows the solution I provided indicates $a = 6$ actually *is* a valid value of $a$, as you also stated yourself. I'll leave it to you, if you wish, to check the result of using the OP's method, and my critique of it, with $a = 0.9$.

Comment: I can create many other cases to bin for $x$ and $a$ values, but what literally asked is "Find the all possible values of $a$" ... Whatever seems framed for this answer ...

Comment: @FarshidFarhat Note that, actually, what is literally being asked is *not* "Find the all possible values of $a$" ... . Instead, that is just part of the problem the OP is trying to solve. They provided their attempt, with their actual question being stated at the end, i.e., "I haven't done the calculation, because I want to make sure that the method I use is correct. Do you see any flaws in the method?" My answer tries to address what the OP is specifically asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a solution different from OP; albeit simpler.

First, transform the condition $\forall x\in (0,2)$. Equivalent to this condition, introduce $x = \frac{2}{y}$ with $y >1$, so only one boundary has to be inspected and the term remains quadratic in $y$ and $a$:

The inequality  $4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4>0$ becomes
$16-4ay+(a^2-5a+4)y^2>0$.

First note that only $a>0$ has to be inspected, since for $y > 1$ and $a \le 0$ we have
$16-4ay+(a^2-5a+4)y^2 > 16  - 9/4 + (-5/2 + a)^2 > 0$ so the condition is always obeyed for $a \le 0$.

Rewrite the question as
$$
16 - 4 a y + (a^2 - 5 a + 4) y^2 = (a y - 2 - \frac{5y}{2})^2 - \frac14 (9 y^2 + 40 y - 48) > 0 \tag{1}
$$
Since $9 y^2 + 40 y - 48 > 0$ always holds for $y >1$, we can discuss $g = (a y - 2 - \frac{5y}{2})^2$. For $a \to 0$, $g \to \frac14 (5y +4)^2 =  \frac14 (16y^2 + 64) + \frac14 (9 y^2 + 40 y - 48)$ so the question's condition is always obeyed. Likewise, for very large $a$ it is clear that (1) will also be obeyed.

Conversely, for $a=4$ we have $16 - 4 a y + (a^2 - 5 a + 4) y^2  = 16(1-y)$ which will be negative for all $y >1$.

Hence the allowed regions for $a$ will be $a_1 > a $   and $a > a_2$ with $a_2 \ge 4 \ge a_1 > 0$.

What remains is to derive $a_1$ and $a_2$ from the roots of (1) and their dependence on $y$. This is standard curve discussion and we give the results.

We have for the smaller root:

$$\frac{1}{y}\Big(2 + \frac{5y}{2} - \frac12 \sqrt{9 y^2 + 40 y - 48}\Big) 
\ge \frac{8}{5 + \sqrt{13}} = a_1 \simeq 0.93 $$
which holds since the minimum occurs at  $ y = 5 + \sqrt{13} > 1$

We have for the larger root:
$$\frac{1}{y}\Big(2 + \frac{5y}{2} + \frac12 \sqrt{9 y^2 + 40 y - 48}\Big) 
\le \frac23 (5 + \sqrt{13})  = a_2 \simeq 5.74 $$
which holds since the maximum occurs at  $ y = 5 - \sqrt{13} > 1$. $\qquad \Box$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, (though strangely written) your method is correct. It can be reformulated noticing more explicitely that $f(x):=4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4$ is decreasing for $x\le a/4$ and increasing for $x\ge a/4$, since $f'(x)=8x-2a.$ We thus recover your 3 cases (and the same numerical results as Andreas, but more directly):

- Case 1: $a/4\ge2$. Then, $f>0$ on $(0,2)$ iff $f(2)\ge0$, i.e. $a^2-9a+20\ge0$, i.e. $a\le2$ or $a\ge4$. This or-condition is always satisfied since $a\ge8$ by hypothesis.
- Case 2: $0<a/4<2$. Then, $f>0$ on $(0,2)$ iff $f(a/4)>0$, i.e. $\frac34a^2-5a+4>0$, i.e. $a<a_1:=\frac{10-2\sqrt{13}}3\approx0.93$ or $a>a_2:=\frac{10+2\sqrt{13}}3\approx5.74.$ This or-condition is satisfied iff $0<a<a_1$ or $a_2<a<8.$
- Case 3: $a/4\le0$. Then, $f>0$ on $(0,2)$ iff $f(0)\ge0$, i.e. $a^2-5a+4\ge0,$ i.e. $a\le1$ or $a\ge4.$ This or-condition is always satisfied since $a\le0$ by hypothesis.

Putting your three cases together gives the whole set of solutions:
$a<a_1$ or $a>a_2.$

Comment: What I found strange was, in each of the 3 cases, to write things like $\dots\implies u<f(x)<v$ instead of $f((0,2))=(u,v),$ which is what you really meant.

Comment: .. to make this "algebra-precalculus" it would perhaps be nice to write (but I don't want to edit answers):  It can be reformulated noticing more explicitely that $f(x):=4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4 = 4\left(x-\frac a4\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4$ is decreasing for $x\le a/4$ and increasing for $x\ge a/4.$

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution sets in your cases:

Case-1) $((-\infty,4)\cup(5,\infty))\cap[8,\infty)=[8,\infty)$

Case-2) $((-\infty,1)\cup(4,\infty))\cap[-\infty,0)=(-\infty,0]$

Case-3) $((-\infty,\frac{10-2\sqrt{13}}{3})\cup(\frac{10+2\sqrt{13}}{3},\infty))\cap[0,8]=[0,\frac{10-2\sqrt{13}}{3})\cup(\frac{10+2\sqrt{13}}{3},8]$

The union of sets we found in all cases is $S=(-\infty,\frac{10-2\sqrt{13}}{3})\cup(\frac{10+2\sqrt{13}}{3},\infty)$.  S is the solution of the problem.

My solution:

$f'(x)=0$ gives the minumum of the quadratic function $f(x)=4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4$ at $x=\frac{a}{4}$ and the solution of the inequality $f(\frac{a}{4})=\frac{3}{4}a^2-5a+4>0$ is the set $S$ above.

If $a$ were in $[\frac{10-2\sqrt{13}}{3},\frac{10+2\sqrt{13}}{3}]$ then $x=\frac{a}{4}$ would be in $(0,2)$ and $f(\frac{a}{4})$ would be non-positive. So, we can conclude that $S$ is the solution set of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've revised your work as follows.

The first step is fine

$$ 0<x<2 \implies -\frac a2<2x-\frac a2<4-\frac a2$$

As a minor issue we should use $\iff$ instead of $\implies$.

- Case $-1:\,\,\,a≥0 \wedge 4-\frac a2≤0$

The condition corresponds to $a\ge8$.

The inequality you reach $\left(4-\frac a2\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0 \iff (a-4)(a-5)>0$ holds.

- Case $-2:\,\,\,a≤0 \wedge 4-\frac a2≥0$

The condition corresponds to $a\le0$.

The inequality you reach $\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0 \iff (a-1)(a-4)>0$ holds.

- Case $-3:\,\,\,a≥0 \wedge 4-\frac a2≥0$

The condition corresponds to $0\le a\le8$. So we could also consider $0<a<8$ but it is not necessary.

The inequality you reach $\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0 \iff a<\frac{10}3-\frac{2\sqrt{13}}3\approx0.93 \land a>\frac{10}3+\frac{2\sqrt{13}}3\approx5.74 $ holds.

The method looks fine to me since you have covered all the cases!

Answer (score 0):

I think your current description is not satisfactory.

Take Case 3 for example. You said,

> This means, $f(x) \ge \frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4$. Thus, for $f(x) > 0$, it
> is enough to take $\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0$ with the restriction $a \ge
>  0\wedge 4-\frac a2\ge 0$.

This description does not emphasize the sufficient and necessary condition to include all possible values of $a$.
It looks (at least from the description) like a sufficient condition (more precisely, $\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4>0$ is a sufficient condition of $f(x) > 0$).

One way to overcome this is given below (Cases 1-2 are omitted here, and given later):

Let
$$f(x) := 4x^2 - 2ax + a^2 - 5a + 4 = \left(2x-\frac a2\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4. \tag{1}$$

We have
$$0 < x < 2 \implies -\frac a2<2x-\frac a2<4-\frac a2. \tag{2}$$

We split into three cases.

**Case 3**: $-\frac{a}2 < 0$ and $4 - \frac{a}2 > 0$, i.e. $0 < a < 8$

Note that $\frac{a}{4} \in (0, 2)$
and $f(\frac{a}{4}) = \frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4$.
We have,
\begin{align*}
 &f(x) > 0, \quad \forall 0 < x < 2\\
 \iff \quad & \frac{3a^2}{4}-5a+4 > 0\\
 \iff \quad & a > \frac{10}{3} + \frac23\sqrt{13}, \quad \mathrm{or} \quad a < \frac{10}{3} - \frac23\sqrt{13}.
\end{align*}
Thus, the set of qualified $a$ is $0 < a < \frac{10}{3} - \frac23\sqrt{13}$
or $\frac{10}{3} + \frac23\sqrt{13} < a < 8$.

---

Someone may ask why I took Case 3 for example, rather than Case 1 or 2? The reason is that the conditions in Case 1 and Case 2 (respectively, $a \ge 8$ and $a \le 0$), actually both imply $f(x) > 0$. By contrast, the condition of Case 3 (i.e. $0 < a < 8$) does not imply $f(x) > 0$.

The details are given below.

**Case 1**: $4 - \frac{a}{2} \le 0$, i.e. $a \ge 8$

From (1) and (2), we have
\begin{align*}
 &0 < x < 2 \\
 \implies\quad & \left(2x-\frac a2\right)^2 > \left(4 - \frac{a}2\right)^2\\
 \implies \quad & f(x) > \left(4 - \frac{a}2\right)^2 + \frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4 = (a - 4)(a - 5) > 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, the set of qualified $a$ is $a \ge 8$.

**Case 2**: $-\frac{a}2 \ge 0$, i.e. $a \le 0$

From (1) and (2), we have
\begin{align*}
 &0 < x < 2 \\
 \implies\quad & \left(2x-\frac a2\right)^2 > \left( - \frac{a}2\right)^2\\
 \implies \quad & f(x) > \left(- \frac{a}2\right)^2 + \frac {3a^2}{4}-5a+4 = (a - 1)(a - 4) > 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, the set of qualified $a$ is $a \le 0$.

Summarily, all possible values of qualified $a$ is $a < \frac{10}{3} - \frac23\sqrt{13}$
or $a > \frac{10}{3} + \frac23\sqrt{13}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $g(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$,if $A>0$, then $g(x)\ge 0$

**Case 1:** $\forall x \in \Re$, if $B^2\le 4AC$.

**Case 2:** For $x \in [p,q]$, if the position of the min (bottom) of $g(x)$, $x_0=-\frac{B}{2A}$ should be s.t $x_0 \le p$ or $x_0\ge q$.

Here $$f(x)=4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4>0$$ in $x\in (0,2)$ can be met in both the cases.

**Case 1:** $4a^2 \le 16(a^2-5a+4) \implies 3a^2-20a+16 \ge 0 \implies (x-x_1)(x-x_2)\ge 0$ where $x_1=\frac{2}{3}(5-\sqrt{13}) \approx 0.92), x_2=\frac{2}{3}(5+\sqrt{13}) \approx 5.73$. So $$a\le \frac{2}{3}(5-\sqrt{13})~ \text{or}~ a\ge \frac{2}{3}(5+\sqrt{13}).....(1)$$

**Case 2:** $x_0=a/4$, $x_0<0 \implies a\le 0$  and $x_0\ge 2 \implies a\ge 8.$
So in this case $$a\le 0 ~\text{or}~ a\ge 8........(2)$$.

Interestingly, the final domain of $a$ needs to be the union of (1) and (2).

Lastly, $f(x)> 0, ~\text{ONLY}~\forall x \in(0,2)$, when $a\in (-\infty,0)\cup (8,\infty).$

Otherwise,  $f(x)>0, \forall x \in \Re $, when $a \in (-\infty,\frac{2}{3}(5-\sqrt{13}) \cup  (\frac{2}{3}(5+\sqrt{13}), \infty)$

Answer (score -2):

Suggestion

In case$-1:\,\,\,a≥0 \wedge 4-\frac a2≤0$ simply means $a \ge 8$.

After re-writing the function in vertex form and plugging in some valid values of a (like 8, 10 etc) will give a graph on quadrant I for x in (0, 2). This means the function is greater than 0 for all x in that domain under that restriction.

Comment: The OP said "I haven't done the calculation, because *I want to make sure that the method I use is correct*." In case 1, completing his own calculation, he would get a proof of the general property you induce from "some valid values" and "a graph".

Answer (score -2):

Might be calculative but this works

Find the roots using quadratic formula then if the condition satisfies then there are 3 cases

$$\text{Case1}:-$$first the smaller of the 2 roots (the one with the negative sign) is greater than 2 this gives the quadratic $a^2-13a-68\ge0$ and $3a^2-20a+16\le0$

$$\text{Case2}:-$$
Again the greater root is less than or equal to 0 $$a^2-5a+4\le0$$ and $3a^2-20a+16\le0$

$$\text{Case3}:-$$
Discriminant is negative ,ie $3a^2-20a+16\ge0$

Solving case by case we get all solutions

Answer (score -2):

I've tried to answer in a way which skips over some of the tedious calculation so as to make it easier to understand what this question means.
$$f(a)=4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4>0$$
Consider, for the moment, $x$ to be a constant. Then we have a quadratic expression in $a$ with roots at (details omitted):
$$a_1=- \sqrt{-3x^2+5x+\tfrac94}+x+\tfrac52$$
$$a_2= \sqrt{-3x^2+5x+\tfrac94}+x+\tfrac52$$
In the range of interest of $x$, it turns out that the expression under the square root is always positive, so we always have two real roots. We can plot the roots as follows:
[image]

We want $f(a)>0$ for all $x \in (0,2)$. It is easy to see that this requires that $a$ is less than the minimum value of $a_1$ or $a$ is greater than the maximum value of $a_2$.
We therefore differentiate $a_1$ and $a_2$ with respect to $x$ (details omitted) to find the turning points which are, for $a_1$:
$$x=\tfrac16(5-\sqrt{13}), \;\; a=-\tfrac23(\sqrt{13}-5)$$
and for $a_2$:
$$x=\tfrac16(5+\sqrt{13}), \;\; a=\tfrac23(\sqrt{13}+5)$$

And our full solution is therefore:
$$a<-\tfrac23(\sqrt{13}-5) \text{ and } a>\tfrac23(\sqrt{13}+5) $$

Answer (score -2):

I want to bring the most straightforward way to calculate this problem systematically. Also, you can check the attached graph for better representation. I write the quadratic equation $f_x(a)=4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4$ w.r.t. $a$ as an unknown parameter. We have:

$f_x(a)=a^2-(2x+5)a+(4x^2+4)>0$.

So, $a$ must be greater than the bigger root of $f_x(a)=0$ or less than the smaller root, which are:

$f_x(a)=0 \rightarrow a=x+2.5\pm\sqrt{-3x^2+5x+2.25}=g^\pm(x)$ for $x\in(0,2)$.

So, we have $a>g^+(x)$ or $a<g^-(x)$ for $\forall x \in (0,2)$, i.e.:

$a>\max_{x\in(0,2)}g^+(x)$ or $a<\min_{x\in(0,2)}g^-(x)$. We have:

$dg^+(x)/dx=0\rightarrow 1+\frac{-6x+5}{2\sqrt{-3x^2+5x+2.25}}=0\rightarrow -12x^2+20x+9=36x^2-60x+25$
$\rightarrow 3x^{2}-5x+1=0\rightarrow x=\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{6}\rightarrow g^+(\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{6})=\frac{2}{3}(5+\sqrt{13})$

Similarly, we have:

$dg^-(x)/dx=0\rightarrow 1-\frac{-6x+5}{2\sqrt{-3x^2+5x+2.25}}=0 \rightarrow x=\frac{5-\sqrt{13}}{6} \rightarrow g^-(\frac{8}{5+\sqrt{13}})=\frac{8}{5+\sqrt{13}}$

So, $a$ range having $f_x(a)=4x^2-2ax+a^2-5a+4>0$ are:

$a>\frac{2}{3}(5+\sqrt{13}) \approx5.7370$ or $a<\frac{8}{5+\sqrt{13}} \approx0.9296$

[image]

Comment: This one is the nice one. Thanks for sharing.